# Drawing lines with core graphics

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I want to draw more than one straight line in core graphics. or save the line and start a new one. I used two variables for touch location and assigned touch location to them in touch Began,Moved,Ended then I used this:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor)
    context?.setLineWidth(5.0)
    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: firstTouchLocation.x, y: firstTouchLocation.y))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lastTouchLocation.x, y: lastTouchLocation.y))
    context?.strokePath()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        firstTouchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        lastTouchLocation = firstTouchLocation
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        lastTouchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        lastTouchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: the line disapears and begins a new one i want to save the line and start a new one

Comment: @MohmedShowekh would you add the describe problem comment to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try drawing the line using CAShapeLayer like so:

```
func addLine(fromPoint start: CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint) {
       let line = CAShapeLayer()
       let linePath = UIBezierPath()
       linePath.move(to: start)
       linePath.addLine(to: end)
       line.path = linePath.cgPath
       line.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
       line.lineWidth = 1
       line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
       self.view.layer.addSublayer(line)
   }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You got to have a model object which represent a line say ex: **LineAnnotation**. **LineAnnotation** will hold start and end points, color and  many others details about the line. Hold every **LineAnnotation**(line) in an array. Iterate through this array and draw line one by one. In your case are drawing using latest data. Previous points which are drawn will e refreshed when you call setNeedsDisplay()

Answer (score 0):

As per apples documentation(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay) **setNeedsDisplay** method redraws your view, so you are left with fresh view with latest line only.

To solve your problem simply pull your code in a method and call that method whenever you made a touch.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    drawLine()
}

func drawLine()
{
 let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor)
context?.setLineWidth(5.0)
context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: firstTouchLocation.x, y: firstTouchLocation.y))
context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lastTouchLocation.x, y: lastTouchLocation.y))
context?.strokePath()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
if let touch = touches.first {
    firstTouchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    lastTouchLocation = firstTouchLocation
    drawLine()
}
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
if let touch = touches.first {
    lastTouchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    drawLine()
}
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
if let touch = touches.first {
    lastTouchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    drawLine()
}

}
```